# Find the Users within X metres of another user. SQL

Tags: sql, postgis, distance

I am attempting to find users who are within R metres of another user (X). We use PostGIS with our SQL database. I am able to extract the Long/Lat from users by using the following query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(location)
FROM api_devicelocation
JOIN api_device a ON api_devicelocation.device_id = a.id
JOIN auth_user au ON a.user_id = au.id
WHERE au.id IN (1323, 1332, 1391, 3887);
```

What I am looking to do is build a query that would allow us to find users within R from the user (for instance 1323). I have found that perhaps using may work, but I can't figure it out.

```
SELECT ST_DWithin(location)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm thinking this type of process must work, as that is how almost all dating apps function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of what user? How are you finding The User which you're using to select other users?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out

```
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
FROM (SELECT
    ST_GeogFromText(st_astext(MAX(location))) As gg1,
    ST_GeogFromText(st_astext(MIN(location))) As gg2
  FROM api_devicelocation
  JOIN api_device a ON api_devicelocation.device_id = a.id
  JOIN auth_user au ON a.user_id = au.id
  WHERE au.id = 1323
    ) As foo  ;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this condition. You can probably find more examples if you look up ST_DistanceSphere

```
.... where ROUND(ST_DistanceSphere(geom_R, geom_X ))  >  (limit in metres) ;
```